# Dynamic reference and increment

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic

I'm trying to dynamically reference a cell that holds a date which I want to increase by one.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("'["&$EU$1&".xlsx]"&$A$1&" "&EU2&"'!$AF:$AF"),
MATCH($E3,INDIRECT("'["&$EU$1&".xlsx]"&$A$1&" "&EU2&"'!$B:$B"),0)),"N/A")
```

In this instance $A$1 hold the date, 2021, which I would like to increment by one to 2022.

Is there a way to accomplish this in the formula?

i.e.

```
..."&SUM($A$1+1)&"...
```

Thanx for looking,
Sam

Comment: Have you tried it (the sum is redundant)?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Should have stated that. Tried PRODUCT as well with no luck.

Comment: This works `=INDIRECT("$A$1")+1` so you should be able to adapt that for your example.

Comment: But surely easier to store the incremented value in another cell.

Comment: It's a "one-off" increment, but over many sheets. It's a complicated mess basically. Thanx for your replies. I'll try to implement when I get back to my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've overcomplicated the solution with the sum approach.

It's simply changing `$A$1` in your formula to `$A$1+1`.  If $A$1 contains 2021, the value being concatenated into your strings will be 2022:

> =IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("'["&$EU$1&".xlsx]"&$A$1+1&"
> "&EU2&"'!$AF:$AF"),   MATCH($E3,INDIRECT("'["&$EU$1&".xlsx]"&$A$1+1&"
> "&EU2&"'!$B:$B"),0)),"N/A")

This of course assumes that A1 contains specifically a year in the form `2021` and not an excel serial date value.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I forgot to change &EU2& to &$EU2& and it wasn't calculating correctly.